# NodeJS http request fails (response is undefined, Exceeded maxRedirects)

Tags: node.js, request, response

Why does this simple request does not work? Why I'm not able to download that website page?

```
var request = require('request');

request({uri: "http://www.abola.pt/nnh/ver.aspx?id=487828", maxRedirects:1}, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(response,error)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, had to specify an user-agent.

```
{url: url2, maxRedirects:1, headers: {'User-Agent': user_agent}}
```